# vue-html-to-paper styles not loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, printing

I am using vue-html-to-paper to print in my vuejs app and followed the doc, but styles is not loading into print window, when click on print getting console log as in pic

```
const options = {
  name: "_blank",
  specs: ["fullscreen=yes", "titlebar=yes", "scrollbars=yes"],
  styles: ["./assets/css/demo.css"],
};
Vue.use(VueHtmlToPaper, options);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using Webpack in your project. If so, you'll need to place the assets directory in your /public directory (not in /src). Webpack ignores everything in that directory and so they are served as usual. [More info](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder)

Short answer: Put your /assets folder in /public and the styles should load.